$\ \lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot x_n. $ using the Stolz–Cesàro theorem
Problem :
Let $k \geq 2$ be an integer. Consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ with $x_0 \in \left( 0, \frac{1}{k} \right)$ and  $ x_{n+1} = x_n (1 - x_n)(1 - 2x_n) \dots (1 - kx_n)$.
Find  $\
\lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot x_n.
$
My attempt(mainly a sketch):
By induction, I’ve proven $x_n \in \left( 0, \frac{1}{k} \right), \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. (*)
Also,
$
\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \leq 1 \implies (x_n)_{n \geq 0} \text{ is decreasing (**) }.$

Thus (from ( * ) and (**), $\implies$ $x_n \to l$, where $l \in \left[ 0, \frac{1}{k} \right]$, and
$
l = l(1-l)(1-2l)\dots(1-kl).
$
Since $l \geq 0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$.
Here I used the Stolz-Cesaro theorem:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\frac{1}{x_n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n (1 - x_n)(1 - 2x_n)\dots(1 - kx_n)}{x_n +x_n (1 - x_n)(1 - 2x_n)\dots(1 - kx_n)  } = ?
$
This is where I got stuck. I guess the limit is
$
\frac{2}{k(k+1)},
$
but I don’t know how to prove it continuing my idea.
What do you think ? I am open to any suggestion, comment or solution. Thank you !

Does $k$ vary??

No , k is a fixed integer.

Your idea is right and you are close to final solution. We have
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}nx_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{\frac{1}{x_n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{x_n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{1-\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}}= $$
$$ =\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_n(1-x_n)\cdot \ldots \cdot (1-kx_n)}{1-(1-x_n)\cdot \ldots \cdot (1-kx_n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_n(1-x_n)\cdot \ldots \cdot (1-kx_n)}{1-1+x_n(1+2+\ldots +k)-x^2_n\sum\limits_{1\leq i < j \leq k}ij+\ldots} =$$
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(1-x_n)\cdot \ldots \cdot (1-kx_n)}{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}-x_n\sum\limits_{1\leq i < j \leq k}ij+\ldots}=\frac{1}{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}=\frac{2}{k(k+1)} $$
Where all these summs in denominator are fixed (they depend only on $k$) so as $x_n\to 0$ they multiplied by $x_n$ also approach $0$.

Thank you so much !
